# Unable to get data from dynamically created textfield in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic, textfield

I have a small project where i created text fields based on user input.

```
$('#arraySizeButton').click(function() {
var arraySize = $("#arraySize").val();
if(arraySize=='') {
    alert("Enter Some Text In Input Field");
}else{
    var count = arraySize;
    var html = [];
    while(count--) {
      html.push("\<input type='text' id='inputTextField", count, "'>");
    }
    $('#inputTextFieldsarea').append(html.join(''));
}
});
```

I want to create a dynamic program based on above code and retrieve data from textfields to an array. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: WHy do you have a \ ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```
html.push("<input type='text' id='inputTextField"+count+"'/>");
```

Comment: var item1 = $('#inputTextField2').val();
 var item2 = $('#inputTextField1').val();
 var item3 = $('#inputTextField0').val(); i'm retrieving data from text field like this. i want to make this part dynamic and add those all text fields to array

Comment: Edited my answer. see if it works

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is add a [] to the name of the input, to let the html form know that this is an array.

You should do something like that:

```
html.push("\<input name='field[]' type='text' id='inputTextField", count, "'>");
```

And using php to get the content of all the POSTed fields you could simply check

> $_POST['field']

which is an array.

---

EDIT: IF you want to do this using jquery as you stated in your comment, then you could do it like that:

```
$('[id^="inputTextField"]').each(function() { 
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: **var item1 = $('#inputTextField2').val(); var item2 = $('#inputTextField1').val(); var item3 = $('#inputTextField0').val();** i'm retrieving data from text field like this. i want to make this part dynamic and add those all text fields to array

Comment: $('[id^="inputTextField"]').each(function() {
   alert($(this).val());
});

Comment: Awesome, thank you this works.

Comment: can you help me to set data for all inputTextFields? same like above. where all inputtextfieds created dynamically.. appreciate it